# Xamarin Forms shell Navigation - different page content for logged user

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I'm making app in Xamarin Forms, and I'd like to have different content of page if user is logged.
I was already trying to achive this with pushModalAsync but result page do not have Flyout menu witch is important to me.

One solution that comes to my mind is to put two different content i want to show in frame and bind this frame`s IsVisible property to IsLogged. Is it better way to do this?

Comment: Yes,it's a way to display two contents by binding the IsVisiable property.

Comment: I`ve chose to do it by ContentView and setting ControlTemplate